# Android Realm, query objects by child attribute

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm using [`Realm-Java`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) for an Android application.

I need to query a list of `MyObject`, searching for the ones that contain a string in `MyObject.SubObject_A.ListOfString`.

Since Realm doesn't support list of `String`, I'm now using this structure:

```
-MyObject
----SubObject_A
--------Attribute_A
--------Attribute_B
--------RealmList<RealmString>
----SubObject_B
----OtherStuff
```

With `RealmString` being

```
public class RealmString extends RealmObject {
  public static final String VALUE = "value";
  private String value;
}
```

How do I query for all `MyObject` that contain a given String inside `MyObject.SubObject_A.RealmList<RealmString>`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're looking at [*link queries*](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#link-queries). You should be able to do something like this to get a `RealmResults<MyObject>`.

```
realm.where(MyObject.class).equalTo("subObject_A.stringList.value", "search string").findAll();
```

The idea is that you're able to use a condition in `equalTo` that contains the path through the relationships separated by period.

Comment: I was sure I read it somewhere, but I couldn't find it anymore. Thank you!